# Swap lines conditionally with awk

Tags: json, awk, sed

I have the following file,

```
{
  "number": "12",
  "question": "Sample Question",
  "options": [
    {
      "text": "sample option 1",
      "type": "check",
      "isAnswer": "false"
    },
    {
      "text": "sample option 2",
      "type": "check",
      "isAnswer": "false"
    },
    {
      "text": "sample option 3",
      "type": "check",
      "isAnswer": "true"
    },
    {
      "text": "sample option 4",
      "type": "check",
      "isAnswer": "true"
    },
    {
      "text": "sample option 5",
      "type": "check",
      "isAnswer": "false"
    }
  ],
  "explanation": "sample explanation",
  "reference": "sample ref"
}
```

I would like to re-order the lines in such a way that `type` comes before `text`.

```
   {
      "type": "check",
      "text": "sample option 1",
      "isAnswer": "false"
    }
```

I know it is doable, I was able to swap some lines by using awk, but not getting the desired results. It seems to be an interesting problem, Can anyone help?

Comment: You have JSON data. Consider using `jq` to parse and filter. Also what is purpose of reordering JSON fields?

Comment: Thank you, `jq` was a good suggestion, I am still exploring this. There is no real use of re-ordering, as on the parser side it will be readable in the expected format, it is just for my own improved readability.

Comment: Since you used the `sed` tag but specified `awk` in the titel, I'll merely suggest `sed '/^ *"text/{h;d;};/^ *"type/G'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this with the following command.

```
awk -v r="text" -v o="type" ' $0 ~ o { s = 1 } $0 ~ r && ! s { cur = $0; getline; print; print cur; next; }  1 ' file.json
```

Comment: That would fail if `text` or `type` showed up in any other context (e.g. `"explanation": "this is some type of textual explanation"`). Also, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for when/how to use `getline` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '$1~/^"text"/{txt=$0; next} {print} txt{print txt; txt=""}' file
{
  "number": "12",
  "question": "Sample Question",
  "options": [
    {
      "type": "check",
      "text": "sample option 1",
      "isAnswer": "false"
    },
    {
      "type": "check",
      "text": "sample option 2",
      "isAnswer": "false"
    },
    {
      "type": "check",
      "text": "sample option 3",
      "isAnswer": "true"
    },
    {
      "type": "check",
      "text": "sample option 4",
      "isAnswer": "true"
    },
    {
      "type": "check",
      "text": "sample option 5",
      "isAnswer": "false"
    }
  ],
  "explanation": "sample explanation",
  "reference": "sample ref"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/"text":/{N;/"type":/s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2\n\1/;P;D}' file
```

If the line following `"text":` contains `"type":`, swap the lines.

N.B. This may ripple a `"text":` line down a file if the there are more than one line containing `"type":` following it.